# Have got short answers

Tags: grammar

I would like to understand which is the correct short answer to the question:

> Have we got ... ?

I found in my child's English book the following example:

> Have we got a dog? 
> Short Answer: Yes, **you** have / No, you haven't
>
> It sounds strange as I would answer
>
> Yes **we** have.

Is this correct ?
Is there a grammar rule to answer with "you" ?

Comment: Hello, DEDE. 'We' is deictic. That means it needs / indicates reference in some greater sphere. 'We had soup for lunch' refers to my wife Catherine and myself, today. What does 'we' refer to in your "Have we got ...?" sentence? "It's great to be back after 3 years in Siberia, Mrs Jackson. I can't wait to see the family. How are they? Any changes? Have we got a dog?" ... "Yes, you have." // "Mum, I'm back ... 3 years in the wilds! Have we got a dog?" ... "Yes, we have!" (Strange conversational opening after 3 years apart!) //// Test questions qare often contrived / silly.

Comment: The "we" might not include the person being asked, who replies "You..."

Comment: Thanks. I got it. The sentence was also included in a test for child at secondary school. The exercise was requesting to write short answers. "Have we got a new English teacher ? Yes you have." and the book Golive 1 from Ocfor is publishing it as correct answer,

Comment: See Wikipedia [***inclusive "we" and exclusive "we".***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity)

Comment: It's much clearer if you swap the pronouns. "Have you got a dog?" "Yes, we have!"

Comment: Using "Have we got ...", in this sense, was always viewed as poor English when I was growing up.  It might be considered correct in the context of "Have we got a winner?", but not in "Have we got a dog?"  "Do we have a dog?" is far better, to my ears.

Comment: I am not sure what a "short answer" is, but the shortest answer is: A: "Have we got a dog? - B:  "Yes / No.".